# ProgressRing is not showed during data loading

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, windows-community-toolkit

I have a `ProgressRing` that I need to show while a list is loaded into a `DataGrid`. When I run the app, the data is loaded, but `ProgressRing`isn't showed. What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <ProgressRing x:Name="CarregamentoDeContas" />

    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="DataGridDeContas"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Contas}" />
</Grid>
```

code-behind:

```cs
    private List<Conta> Contas;

    private void ObterListaDeContas()
    {
        try
        {
            CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = true;
            Contas = ListaDeContas.ObterContas();
        }
        finally
        {
            CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    public ContasPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ObterListaDeContas();
    }
```

Comment: hi @joao please try just your progress ring by commenting controls:DataGrid and finnaly block may be you datagrid is superpossed on your progress ring

Answer (score 0):

> ProgressRing is not showed during data loading

Please check `ObterListaDeContas` method, it has not contain async calling, it means that 
`IsActive` property of `CarregamentoDeContas` will be set as false directly. if you want show progress ring, you could set task delay in `ObterListaDeContas` method or make `ObterContas()` as asynchronous method and call it with await method.

```
private async void ObterListaDeContas()
{
    try
    {
        CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = true;

        //The progress will last for two seconds
        await Task.Delay(2000);

    }
    finally
    {
        CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using "async void", maybe it would be better:

```
    //create Task<bool>
    private async Task<bool> ObterListaDeContas()
    {
        try
        {
            //ProgressRing activation
            CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = true;

            //DoSomethingBig() or await Task.Delay(3000)-only for learning
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            //catch your exceptions
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void DeactiveProgressBar(bool isDone)
    {
        //ProgressRing deactivation when the task is over
        CarregamentoDeContas.IsActive = false;

        //optional
        if (isDone)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Data loaded");
            //Unblock Button, DoSomething() etc...
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Data NOT Loaded");
            //give a warning message to the user
        }
    }
```

Using this method:

```
DeactiveProgressBar(await ObterListaDeContas());
```

It works as intended with the UWP application.